# Universal links for Windows phone app

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework, windows-phone

I am using ionic to develop my application and need a feature in which " an URL when clicked should detect whether app. is present or not-- If not re-direct to browser web page.".
I am able to achieve this for Android and iOS with the help of cordova plugin.
This plugin does not support Windows phone.
How to do this for Windows phone ?

Comment: @hirro I think you have this feature enabled.Can you help me here.

Comment: @PaulAnnetts .. I saw your post related to this. Can you please provide soln.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are talking about [URI associations for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx).

Shortly, you should create specific URI (calling protocol) for the target/wanted application, and call `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(target_app_URI);` If this app already installed, it will be launched and get your parameters (specified in launching URI), if not, WP will open "Store" app and will locate and show target application.

So, to achieve your needs, do the following:

- create your WP app with URI scheme support (i.e. your own "protocol"), by following MS recommendation from the link above
- publish your app on Windows store
- add link to your app to html code (here is [launch page sample](http://senssoft.com/urilaunch.htm) for my app "SilverDict")
- tap this link on the phone browser: it will launch the app if installed, or open app page in the store

Comment: I am looking for something where my URL is "https://****.com" and when clicked should ask for app if installed. Also am looking for cutom URL like https://****.com which can be used for all platforms.Please correct if I missed anything.

Comment: I think this is how app to app communicates .. but my case is to launch app. from any open customised URL like https://****.com

Comment: If you are talking about click/tap on URL in browser, and browser should launch app - it's not possible (fortunately!) at all on WP.
Could you provide example, how you launching app on Android from the browser?

Comment: Android and iOS am able to achieve through deep linking approach. Settings are done in manifest files which mentions all the details like host name, scheme, path etc.

Comment: OK, I was wrong: URI launch scheme works fine for browser urls. So, please follow guide link posted in my answer. What do you need:
1. Create app with your own URI scheme (protocol).  2. Publish it on Windows store. 3. Place a link on your web-page (for example, this is a link for my "SilverDict" app `<a href="silverdict://">Click here to launch/install SilverDict</a>`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But my plan is to have single webpage URL like "https://****.com", when, on clicked will show options open with "App" or "Browser." This approach works fine with Android and iOS. The only problem is am not getting any soln for Windows. The approach which you said , i think may work only for app. to app. communication. Please correct if i went wrong. Meanwhile, I will try that approach too.

Comment: As far as I remember, http & https URI schemes are reserved for default web browser so (I afraid) you can't reserve https for your WP app.
By the way, I don't see any real problem: for example, on your web site you can detect browser's user agent, and for WP case change open link from https (in case for iOS and Android) to your custom protocol for Windows phone.

Comment: Finally got it .. Expected solution is here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt670665.aspx